# Recents posts pulling from different post type

Tags: page-template, blog

This blog page is pulling from a Page Template called full-width-blog.php. The left of the content is where the supposed general posts should appear. On the right is the sidebar.

How could you make the main left area pulling from Recent Articles and not from Testimonials?

See image for an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83SyI.png

full-width-blog: http://pastebin.com/R6BD1R8u

Comment: sidebar.php: http://pastebin.com/YDGuR8GH

Comment: Is this a simple thing to do? Do I need to add other php files to pastebin?

Comment: should be simple and your code is fine except you are using `query_posts` over and over on the same page(sidebar) use either `get_posts` or `wp_query` instead and reset the Query after each one using `wp_reset_query`

Comment: @Bainternet - I don't know how to do that.

Comment: here you go http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: @Bainternet - I added       <?php 
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=testimonial' );
 
   ?> --- but now it gotten even messier

Comment: I quit. I don't understand this. Thanks anyway. I'll accept you as the right answer. Post in an answer so that I can accept your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an attempt to fix your sidebar code :

```
<div id="rightcolumn-wrapper">
  <div class="rightcolumn-inner">

    <?php   /* Widgetized sidebar */

        if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar') ) : ?>


     <?php /* If a title has been provided, we'll use that. */
             $NewsTitle=get_option('NewsTitle');
            if ($NewsTitle) { 
            echo ' <h3 class="news">';            
             echo $NewsTitle;
            echo '</h3>';
            // Otherwise we'll use a generic message.
            } else { ?>
      <h3>Recent News</h3>
      <?php } ?>

    <?php 
                $News=get_option("News");
                $news_Query =  new WP_Query(array(
                  'cat' => $News,
                  'posts_per_page' => get_option("newspostlimit"),
                  'post_type' => 'post'
                )); 
    ?><ul class="news">
    <?php while ($news_Query->have_posts()) : $news_Query->the_post(); ?>
      <li> 
        <strong><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> : </strong>
        <br />
        <?php the_title(); ?> :
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> 
        <?php the_content_rss('cut', TRUE, '', 20); ?>
        </a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="view-more">&nbsp;</a>
      </li>      
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>

    <?php /* If a title has been provided, we'll use that. */
    $TestimonialTitle=get_option('TestimonialTitle');
    if ($TestimonialTitle) { 
      echo ' <h3 class="news">';            
      echo $TestimonialTitle;
      echo '</h3>';
    // Otherwise we'll use a generic message.
    } else { ?>
      <h3>Testimonial</h3>
    <?php 
    }
    $Testimonial=get_option("Testimonial");
    $testi_Query = new WP_Query(array('cat'=> $Testimonial, 'posts_ter_page' =>  get_option("Testimonialpostlimit"))); 
    ?>
    <ul class="testimonial">
    <?php while ($testi_Query->have_posts()) : $testi_Query->the_post(); ?>
      <li> 
        <?php the_content_rss('cut', TRUE, '', 20); ?>
        <br />
        <strong>
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </strong>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="view-more">&nbsp;</a>
      </li>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>


    <ul>
      <li>
        <?php /* If a title has been provided, we'll use that. */
          $ContactInfoTitle=get_option('ContactInfoTitle');
          if ($ContactInfoTitle) { 
            echo ' <h3 class="contact-info">'.$ContactInfoTitle.'</h3>';
             // Otherwise we'll use a generic message.
          } else { ?>
            <h3 class="contact-info">Contact Info</h3>
          <?php 
          }
          $ContactInfo=get_option('ContactInfo');
          if ($ContactInfo) { 
            echo stripslashes($ContactInfo);           
            // Otherwise we'll use a generic message.
          } else { ?>
            <p>Mauris a libero metus, vel blandit lectus. Praesent egestas ultrices turpis eget vestibulum. Pellentesque ligula sem, porta nec venenatis vel, volutpat non tortor. </p>
          <?php } ?>
    </li>
  </ul>



    <ul>
    <li>
      <?php /* If a title has been provided, we'll use that. */
             $SocialTitle=get_option('SocialTitle');
            if ($SocialTitle) { 
              echo ' <h3 class="news">'.$SocialTitle.'</h3>';
            // Otherwise we'll use a generic message.
            } ?>
      <div class="socil-book-marks">
      <?php 
      $TwitterID=get_option('TwitterID');
     $FacebookID=get_option('FacebookID');
      $FlickrID=get_option('FlickrID');
     $DeliciousID=get_option('DeliciousID');
     $TechnoratiID=get_option('TechnoratiID');


      if($TwitterID) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_option('TwitterID'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/twitter.png" alt="twitter" /></a> 
      <?php }       
    if($FacebookID) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_option('FacebookID'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="myspace" /></a>
         <?php }       
    if($FlickrID) { ?>
       <a href="<?php echo get_option('FlickrID'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/flicker.png" alt="flickr" /></a>
           <?php }       
    if($DeliciousID) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_option('DeliciousID'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/delicious.png" alt="delicious" /></a> 
           <?php }       
    if($TechnoratiID) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_option('TechnoratiID'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/technorati.png" alt="technorati" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
         </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- End Main section #main  -->
<div class="clear"></div>
```